# Tkinter window closes pyttsx3

Tags: python, tkinter, pyttsx3

```
from tkinter import *
import pyttsx3

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x500")


def talk():
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.say(my_entry.get())

    my_entry.delete(0, END)
    engine.runAndWait()


my_entry = Entry(root, font=("Helvetica", 28))
my_entry.pack(pady=20)
my_button = Button(root, text="Speak", command=talk)
my_button.pack(pady=20)
root.mainloop()
```

I am trying to run this simple program but the **window only runs once and closes automatically**. The Tkinter window closes after only running one time.
Any suggestions? Some people suggested threading but I don't know how to use it, if anyone of you knows where I can learn that, it will be helpful.

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems with your code. I suspect that an exception occurs in `pyttsx3`. Try running your script from the command line. That would at least *show* any exceptions that occur.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try running the `pyttsx3` calls in a separate thread, it should be fairly straightforward to implement

```
import pyttsx3
from threading import Thread
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x500")


def _talk_target():  # renamed 'talk' function for clarity
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.say(my_entry.get())

    my_entry.delete(0, END)
    engine.runAndWait()


def talk():  # this is now the 'talk' function that's called by 'my_button'
    tts = Thread(target=_talk_target)  # init a new thread to call '_talk_target'
    tts.start()  # run '_talk_target' in a new thread
    tts.join()  # rejoin the main thread


my_entry = Entry(root, font=("Helvetica", 28))
my_entry.pack(pady=20)
my_button = Button(root, text="Speak", command=talk)
my_button.pack(pady=20)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: this helps me understand how to use threads but still doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Ah darn, sorry friend. Glad I could provide some info for you at least. If you think this is useful as a reference, I'll leave it up. Otherwise, I'm happy to delete this answer.

Comment: thanks, no need to delete

Answer (score 0):

Work around:

```
from subprocess import call
phrase = "Hi everyone"
call(["python3", "speak.py", phrase])
```

where speak.py is:

```
import sys
import pyttsx3

def init_engine():
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    return engine

def say(s):
    engine.say(s)
    engine.runAndWait() #blocks

engine = init_engine()
say(str(sys.argv[1]))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).